# All of the Torah contained within the Ten Commandments

Tags: aseres-hadibros

I have heard (read?) that all of the Torah is contained within the Aseret HaDibrot. Where is this from?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8186/why-the-specific-commandments-in-the-aseret-hadibrot

Answer (score 1):

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.24.12?lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Exodus.24.13.1&lang2=bi) writes this in the name of Rav Saadia Gaon:

> את לחת האבן והתורה והמצוה אשר כתבתי להורתם. כָּל שֵׁשׁ מֵאוֹת וּשְׁלֹשׁ עֶשְׂרֵה מִצְווֹת בִּכְלַל עֲשֶׂרֶת הַדִּבְּרוֹת הֵן, וְרַבֵּנוּ סְעַדְיָה פֵּרֵשׁ בָּאַזְהָרוֹת שֶׁיָּסַד לְכָל דִּבּוּר וְדִבּוּר מִצְווֹת הַתְּלוּיוֹת בּוֹ:
> את לחת האבן והתורה והמצוה אשר כתבתי להורתם
> [AND I WILL GIVE THEE] THE TABLETS OF STONE, AND THE LAW, AND THE COMMANDMENT WHICH I HAVE WRITTEN TO TEACH THEM — All the six hundred and thirteen commandments are implicitly contained in the Ten Commandments and may therefore be regarded as having been written on the tablets. Rabbi Saadia specified in the אזהרות which he has composed those commandments which may be associated with each of the Ten Commandments.

אזהרות is the term for a poem outlining the 613 commandments.

In addition, the Mossad Harav Kook edition of the Ramban's writings contains an essay explaining how all 613 commandments are derived from the Ten Commandments.